# LINQ/WCF "Sequence contains no elements" & "Value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have 3 out of 4 of my CRUD services *failing due to the following situation.
I am using C# with linq and WCF data services.
I have the following operation contracts:

```
    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteRecord(int vehicleIDDel);

    [OperationContract]
    VehicleStockItem SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID);

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateVehicleDetails(int vehicleIDUpd);
```

What is happening exactly: I am trying to do basic crud processes via a console application. The update & delete services BOTH work but stop the program from running. What I mean by this is that they will update and delete whatever ID is passed to them but both stop the program from running because the query seems to be passing back an empty sequence, or if using the FirstOrDefault passes back a null element which is not allowed according to the debugger.

The code for these two services are as follows:

```
    public void DeleteRecord(int vehicleIDDel)
    {

        VehicleStockItem vehicle =
         (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
          where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleIDDel
          select v)
          .FirstOrDefault();

        db.VehicleStockItems.Remove(vehicle);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
    public void UpdateVehicleDetails(int vehicleIDUpd)
    {
        VehicleStockItem vehicle =
            (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
             where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleIDUpd
             select v).FirstOrDefault();



        vehicle.Sold = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

As I said both of these actually change the records they are supposed to but both throw an error and stop the program from running.

Update error:
http://s23.postimg.org/cgvzax0nf/update_Error.jpg

Delete Error:
http://s28.postimg.org/dbdkb6m59/delete_Error.jpg

Next up is the retrieve service.

This doesn't seem to work at all, not even if I am putting values directly into the WCF test client.

The code I have for this service is as follows:

```
     public VehicleStockItem SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID)
    {

        VehicleStockItem vehicle =
            (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
             where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleID
             select v
             ).FirstOrDefault();
        return vehicle;
    }
```

This gives the following error when I run it on a record the exists:
http://s28.postimg.org/i67o5aowt/error_WCF.jpg

Can somebody please explain where I am going wrong and why I am getting these errors. Please provide examples in your answer as I am quite novice with this language and using WCF data services.

If you need more information please ask.

Edit:

This is what is being submitted to delete:

```
         Console.Write("Enter ID of Vehicle to delete: ");
         int vehicleIDDel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         vehicleRef.DeleteRecord(vehicleIDDel);
```

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace for the first two methods? If the entities are being updated, it's clearly not that section of the code that's throwing the exception.

Comment: @Rob How do I access the stack trace for these errors. Here are some screen shots: Updating: http://s23.postimg.org/cgvzax0nf/update_Error.jpg Deleting: http://s28.postimg.org/dbdkb6m59/delete_Error.jpg

Comment: In that case the vehicle does not exist.. and whatever is calling your method is passing an invalid Id. This means that the method is *not* updating the vehicles. If you are calling it a bunch of times, maybe *some* work, but not all. So either add a null check, or fix the Ids you are passing to the methods.

Comment: The ID passed to them exists within the database. It always seems to return null, why is this?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at `VehicleStockItemID`, and not another field? Since you said it works and updates vehicles, I'm guessing you're calling the method many times with different IDs. There is definitely at least one Id which does not exist in the database. When the exception happens, put your mouse on `vehicleIDUpd`, get the value and then run this in the db: `SELECT * FROM VehicleStockItems WHERE VehicleStockItemID = {value}`.

Comment: Ah this makes more sense.. When I hover over the value it says 0 even though that's not what I've been typing in... I will update the question to show what the console is submitting.

Answer (score 0):

The two screenshots, one for update and one for delete, are because when you say FirstOrDefault() on the query to pull back the vehicle like:

```
VehicleStockItem vehicle =
            (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
             where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleID
             select v
             ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here vehicle is null, so when you call a property on it, it is null and throws this exception.  The question to research is why vehicleID is not matching....

Comment: Yes I see this now. vehicleIDDel seems to be 0 regardless of what I submit from the console app. So it's searching for 0 which doesn't exist when it should be searching for 16 in example.